# Markov Regression returns nan for some statisics

Tags: regression, statsmodels

I am running a 3 regime states markov model with no trend on data that has been differenced (1st order derivative).

I am returned with a summary:

```
                         Markov Switching Model Results                        
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                   26_1   No. Observations:                44505
Model:               MarkovRegression   Log Likelihood              218613.484
Date:                Tue, 31 Mar 2020   AIC                        -437208.968
Time:                        20:13:59   BIC                        -437130.638
Sample:                             0   HQIC                       -437184.298
                              - 44505                                         
Covariance Type:               approx                                         
                             Regime 0 parameters                              
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma2      4.563e-08        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
                             Regime 1 parameters                              
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma2       3.82e-06   6.06e-08     63.014      0.000     3.7e-06    3.94e-06
                             Regime 2 parameters                              
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma2      5.707e-06   7.48e-08     76.278      0.000    5.56e-06    5.85e-06
                         Regime transition parameters                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p[0->0]        0.3606      0.008     43.096      0.000       0.344       0.377
p[1->0]        0.3023      0.010     31.219      0.000       0.283       0.321
p[2->0]        0.0192      0.007      2.690      0.007       0.005       0.033
p[0->1]        0.5936      0.018     32.775      0.000       0.558       0.629
p[1->1]        0.6976      0.006    119.569      0.000       0.686       0.709
p[2->1]     2.789e-15      0.007   4.12e-13      1.000      -0.013       0.013
==============================================================================
```

What does mean to be returned a summary where sigma2 for regime 0 has nan for some of it stats? Moreover why does this happen and in general what are the ways to mitigate this?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure what's going on just based on your example. However, it should not generally return NaN values, and this is likely a problem with the numerical computation of the Hessian matrix that is used to compute standard errors in Statsmodels. If you are not using v0.11 of Statsmodels, you should upgrade, as there were improvements in the numerical accuracy of the Markov switching models that were introduced in that version. You could also submit a bug report at https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/new.

Comment: hi, this has solved the issue, thanks chad, incidentally is out of sample prediction now added in version 0.11.1? and how do you add more than 1 exog variable, i cannot seem to get it to work.